# How to change Z and Y on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using a Bosnian QWERT**Z** keyboard on Ubuntu 17.10. When I press <kbd>Z</kbd> it types “Y”. How can I swap Z and Y?

I've tried changing file in "X 11", but it didn't help.

Comment: Why don't you add the correct keyboard layout instead?

Comment: Keyboard layout is Bosnian, keyboard  Bosnian

Comment: There are 4 Bosnian layouts available in Ubuntu and you need to choose the one that matches. OSes can at best guess the correct layout based on your location so typically they default to the QWERTY one. Adding/removing keyboard layouts is preferably done during the installation but can be done afterwards anytime.

Comment: @MichaelBay Can you post an answer about that?

Comment: I bet it has German layout on sale.  I met such a case.

Comment: @EliahKagan I know nothing about keyboards from that part of the world and I don't know which one is correct for the OP.  I think the ones with "US" are QWERTY and can be excluded. Don't know which one of the remaining two though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bosnian keyboard layouts are actually different variants of the Serbian layouts. It sounds to me as if you may want to try the *Serbian (Latin qwerty)* layout.

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "latinyz" {
    // For those who insist on using "english-position" Z and Y.

    include "rs(latin)"
    name[Group1]= "Serbian (Latin qwerty)";

    key <AD06> { [ y,              Y             ] }; // y
    key <AB01> { [ z,              Z             ] }; // z
};
```

*Edit:*

I see now that there is an alternative name to access the above keyboard layout: *Bosnian (US keyboard with Bosnian letters)*. Selecting that layout results in exactly the same mapping as *Serbian (Latin qwerty)*.

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "us" {

    include "rs(latinyz)"
    name[Group1]= "Bosnian (US keyboard with Bosnian letters)";
};
```

Comment: thx it worked, but its funny that Bosnian and Croatian layout uses serbian latin layout since serbs use cyrilic

Comment: @vergnujum Serbian can be written in Cyrillic or Latin.

Comment: @vergnujum: There are both cyrillic and latin Serbian layouts. The Bosnian layouts pick some of the latin ones, but not this particular one which switches y and z.

Comment: @wjandrea i know it can but isnt more logic to use Croatian or Bosnian as base, why to choose serbian as base. Greeks also use latin in writing but you still wont use greek as base for lets say Albanian. The point is why is serbian base for Bosnian or Croatian and not for example Croatian?

Comment: @vergnujum: I edited my answer. You may well use one of the Bosnian variants instead to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Gunnar Hjalmarsson thx, it helped